# Enabling restarting in Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, reboot

When I use `shutdown -r` or `shutdown /r` my Windows computer doesn't restart.   I think this command is disabled. How can I enable this command in the command prompt?

Comment: Neither are valid: try 'shutdown /r' or 'shutdown /t 10'

Comment: sorry that is a type wrong . (edit the post)
sry a lot

Comment: Windows XP, Vista or 7 and which flavor (32-bit, 64-bit, Ultimate, etc)?

Answer (score 1):

Run `regedit` (`Start -> Run`) and check these registry keys if `NoClose` is set:

- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer`
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer`

`0` indicates shutdown is enabled.
`1` indicates shutdown is disabled.

If the value is not there, you could try adding it and setting it to `0`. You'll probably need to restart as well.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer SysInternals `PSSHUTDOWN`,which has lots of options. Learn more: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062